# How do i post a document in stackoverflow site for answers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions

How I post a document to others in this (Stack overflow) site for answers.Thanks in advance

Comment: If by document, you mean question, well, you just did!

Comment: Hi Sairam, for questions about Stack Overflow, check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You don't post documents here. You post well-formed and concise questions, and then you get helpful answers.

Comment: For really long code, you can try http://www.pastebin.com/

Answer (score 1):

If by document you mean long parts of text we suggest you don't. The point is to answer in the smallest most concise manner to get to the heart of the manner. If you wish you can post an except from something. Then link to the document so others can read it in its entirety.